# django controller to by default call one function

Tags: django, controller

I was researching on this for quite a bit. I have a use case where the same task has to be performed in all functions of a controller, is there a way to by default call that function in the controller? Aside from creating a method and calling it in each function.

Currently that is what I am doing, but would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/middleware/) class, implementing `process_request(self, request)` with functionality that must be executed before view method will be called. Don't forget to add class name to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in your settings file.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is custom decorators. 
This link would help: http://www.djangofoo.com/253/writing-django-decorators

Comment: Yeah, I have it that way now actually, but was curious if all functions in the controller could just use it by default

Comment: You can write a middleware which decorates all your view functions as default. Try google for "middleware decorate all view functions".

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap `dispatch`, as it is silently invoked around all the other action methods